# Remove data from linq relation

Tags: linq-to-sql, cascade, entityset

If i have a sq-table relation model that looks like this:

```
Project <----> ProjectActivity <----> Activity
```

Where Project and Activity has many to many connections via ProjectActivity and i want to remove a ProjectActivity (not just set its Projekt FK to null). How to i do this?

If I on the EntitySet takes `Project.ProjectActivities.Clear();` the relation will be deletet but the ProjectActivity row will still be there with null reference to Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataContext.ProjectActivities.DeleteAllOnSubmit(Project.ProjectActivities);
```

that should work, you have to delete them not just clear relations